# How can I find shared storage servers

Tags: linux, shared-storage

Among an inventory of 100 servers, mostly SLES and RHEL, how would I find which servers are sharing storage? [It can be clustered File system i.e. OCFS,GPFS,... or distributed file systems i.e GlusterFS or Ceph ... or Network attached storage]

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify what you mean by "sharing", but I suspect you either mean NFS or SMB/CIFS.

Either of those two (or any other type of networked storage) should be easily detected by doing a quick `nmap` port scan ([NFS](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/nfs-ls.html), [SMB/CIFS](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/smb-enum-shares.html)).

There is no magic way to tell if a server is "sharing storage". You're going to need to code up some custom script to run against your servers, taking into account the various types of storage you're hoping to detect.

As an aside, documentation on the results of this would probably be in order as well. It's generally ill-advised to maintain a bunch of servers whose functions you aren't sure of.